Import Error Resolution in Python: Pylint Compliance vs. Runtime Execution
I have the following folder structure:
├── docs
├── setup.py
├── python_package_
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── __main__.py
│   ├── __version__.py
│   ├── arg_parser.py
│   ├── classes
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   └── file_generator.py
│   ├── settings.py
│   ├── python_package.py
│   └── utils
│       ├── __init__.py
│       └── cli.py
├── README.md    
├── requirements.txt
└── tests

The content of the __main__.py file is:
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""Main module for the program."""

from arg_parser import parse_arguments
from utils import cli
from python_package import package
import settings


def main():
    """Main"""
    args = parse_arguments()
    cli.print_argument_summary(args)
    package(args)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
    

When I run python3 python_package/__main__.py ...  it works fine, but if I use pylint to improve my code quality on the __main__.py file it returns me:
************* Module python_package.__main__
__main__.py:4:0: E0401: Unable to import 'arg_parser' (import-error)
__main__.py:5:0: E0401: Unable to import 'utils' (import-error)
__main__.py:7:0: E0401: Unable to import 'settings' (import-error)

------------------------------------------------------------------
Your code has been rated at 0.00/10 (previous run: 0.00/10, +0.00)

If I change the import in the following way, i.e. using the dot notation:
from .arg_parser import parse_arguments
from .utils import cli
from .python_package import python_package
from . import settings

Pylint gives me a score of 10.00/10, but the code doesn't work anymore and gives me this error:
ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package

What am I doing wrong? What is the best way to solve this "problem"?
Thank you
